# Problems in starting Virtual Machines after making my PC dual bootable

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, dualboot

I have a laptop, its model is: HP Pavilion Power Laptop 15-cb0xx (12GB RAM, 4 cores, 8 processors).

It has windows 10 Pro as an operating system.

I have installed virtual box on it, then I have created 3 virtual machines:

```
1- windows 7

2- windows server 2016

3- kali linux
```

They (the 3 VM) were working correctly, until I make my hp laptop dual bootable, with kali Linux as the second OS.

When I boot on `windows 10`, I tried to open each VM, but each one gives me an error:

`windows 7` stucks at "`windows is loading files`".

`windows server` opens windows boot manager and says that windows failed  to start with `0xc000035a` as a status.

`kali Linux` shows me an error before booting :

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).


Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

What happened and what should I do?

(Edit: after marking the VT-x/AMD-V checkbox in kali Linux VM settings, kali now does not show me the same error, but it stucks at a black screen).

Comment: You should reenable VT-x (Intel Hardware Virtualization)

Comment: Did you reset the BIOS when you installed linux in order to boot from USB? this will disable VT-x which is required for 64bit VM emulation. As Ramhound suggests (and so does the error), you need to enable this again.

Comment: I entered to BIOS -> System configuration -> Virtualization tech, and I found it enabled.
Also, I opened each virtual machine settings -> System -> Acceleration, then I checked the VT-x/AMD-V box. But nothing changed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, by removing each virtual machine, and keeping the .vmdk file, then creating 3 virtual machines then implementing the correspondent .vmdk file.